# Number of strings with length m and constant L1-distance over the natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am considering the set of natural numbers {0,1,2,3,...}. I am interested in the number $N(m,w)$ of strings of length $m$ over the natural numbers with a given L1-weight $w$.

The L1-weight, also called the Taxicab- or Manhattan-weight, is defined as $w=\sum_{j=1}^m |x_i|$, where $x=x_1x_2...x_m$.

Is there a closed expression for the number $N(m,w)$?

Comment: Just to make sure, $w = 13$ could be a word of length $1$ with $x_1 = 13$?

Comment: Also, did you try anything already?

Comment: @RSerrao: Yes, it's true. I am still trying....

Comment: Since you're working over the naturals, the absolute value sign is superfluous. You're just looking for $\sum x_i=w$. So isn't that just the standard stars'n'bars thing?

Comment: You're right, the absolute value sign is unnecessary. Never heard about stars'n'bars. I will look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before, this is a stars'n'bars problem. I'll answer the question just to complete this topic.

The interested number can be computed by 
$$
N(m,w) = \binom{w+m-1}{w} = \binom{w+m-1}{m-1}.
$$

A very good proof and example are given here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/